# Setting up server to receive facebook updates regarding a user subscribed facebook page

Tags: android, facebook, server-side, google-cloud-messaging

I am building an android app which implements push messaging usin GCM.For that i have to build  a server and configure it to receive updates from a user subscribed facebook page.
this what i intend to do:
Facebook updates <------ Request and response ---->My Server

Can anyone please suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the Realtime Updates API? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1

This should fit in your Use Case quite well I think...

Comment: Thanx alot...will there be something similar available fr youtube api too?

Comment: That's another question. If my answer helped you please accept accept it.

Comment: @Tobi...yes it did help..the API you suggested should make my life easier... :)   i jst want to know whether there will be similar api for other websites too?

Comment: Then accept it. Read the StackOverflow guidelines regarding asking questions.